# Iterate the Map

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have create a Map like:

```
Map<Id, List<Case>> Mapcase = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();
```

which is giving the result as
     Id of Account as key value and List of case as value of map. i want to iterate all the cases of account and need to do some calculations.

```
List<Account> listaccount = new List<Account>([SELECT Id, 
                                          FROM Account where ID IN: mapCase.KeySet()]);
    for(Account  acc : listaccount){

        for(List<Case> lstc : mapcase.values()){
            for (Case c : lstc)
            {
                if (c.Date__c!= null) {

                    if (math.abs(c.Date__c.daysBetween(system.today())) < 28) {

                    }
                    else if (math.abs(c.Date__c.daysBetween(system.today())) > 28) { }
                }
                if(GetCreatedYearofCase(c)){
                   ..
                }
            }

        }

            setacc.add(acc);

    }
    lstAcc.addAll(setacc);
```

but it is calculating all the cases
i am having doubt, that i am making mistake on

```
for(List<Case> lstc : mapcase.values()){
```

line. but not able to rectify it.

please help me to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code you have written to group accounts to list cases which belong to the same account?

Comment: The source code seems copy-pasted from a project and it seems that OP didn't open the documentation of the map class (use of the get on a map). Helping him is noble but, IMHO, stackexchange is not meant to be a 'do my job' forum. Isn't he supposed to anonymize the code (legal purpose) and to thouroughly search for an answer (source : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and show attempts ? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work on the list of Cases related to the Account instance `acc`, then the code would be:

```
for(Account  acc : listaccount){
    ...
    List<Case> lstc = mapcase.get(acc.Id);
    if (lstc != null) {
        for (Case c : lstc) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The `null` check is needed if you don't have a non-null value for every `Account` in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `get method` to access the list of cases by the passing account ID. You will get a list of cases for that particular Account.

> mapcase.values() contains the list of caseList,In that case you will
>   looping all the cases repeatedly

```
List<Account> listaccount = new List<Account>([SELECT Id, No_of_blades_docked_in_last_1_year__c, No_of_blades_docked_in_last_28_days__c,GE90_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c,GE90_100_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c,GENx_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c,GENx1B_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c,GENx2B_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c 
                                      FROM Account where ID IN: mapCase.KeySet()]);

for(Account  acc : listaccount){
    integer less_28 = 0;
    integer more_28 = 0;
    integer GE90 = 0 ;
    integer GE90_100 = 0;
    integer GENx_1B = 0 ;
    integer GENx_2B = 0;
    integer GENx = 0;

    List<Case> lstc = new list<case>();
    lstc.addAll(mapcase.get(acc.id)); 

/* Here You were looping through all the cases instead we get the list of cases using the account ID*/

        for(case c: lstc){
            if (c.Dock_Date__c != null) {
                System.debug('CFAN_DockDateCalculationTrigger: chp-2:   ' + c.Dock_Date__c);
                if (math.abs(c.Dock_Date__c.daysBetween(system.today())) < 28) {
                    less_28++;
                    more_28++;
                }
                else if (math.abs(c.Dock_Date__c.daysBetween(system.today())) > 28) {more_28++; }
            }
            if(GetCreatedYearofCase(c)){
                if(c.Programme__c == 'GE90'){ GE90++; }
                if(c.Programme__c == 'GE90-100'){ GE90_100++; }
                if(c.Programme__c == 'GEnx-1B'){ GENx_1B++; }
                if(c.Programme__c == 'GEnx-2B'){ GENx_2B++; }
                if(c.Programme__c == 'GE9X'){ GENx++; }
            }
        } 
    acc.No_of_blades_docked_in_last_28_days__c = less_28;
        acc.No_of_blades_docked_in_last_1_year__c = more_28;
        acc.GE90_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c = GE90;
        acc.GE90_100_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c =GE90_100;
        acc.GENx_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c = GENx;
        acc.GENx1B_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c = GENx_1B;
        acc.GENx2B_Direct_Discount_Discount_Price__c = GENx_2B;
        setacc.add(acc);

}
lstAcc.addAll(setacc);
```

Comment: Thank you so much , Dinesh. it helps me a lot. I understand my  mistake from your solution.

Comment: Glad I helped You @AtulPandey